# Performance difference between defining subentities vs using a type column

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Say I want to create one big table for numerous entities that have the same properties, for example categories.

There are several top-level categories that never change, e.g. A, B & C. All other categories are either a child of these top-level categories or related categories.

Which approach would be more performant:

1. Make A, B & C an enum column in the database and give top-level categories no parent.

```
| id | name          | type | parentId |
|----|---------------|------|----------|
| 1  | Category 1    | A    |          |
| 2  | Category 2    | B    |          |
| 3  | Category 3    | C    |          |
| 4  | Subcategory 1 | A    | 1        |
```

2. Make A, B & C top-level rows under which all other categories are nested.

```
| id | name          | parentId |
|----|---------------|----------|
| 1  | Category 1    |          |
| 2  | Category 2    |          |
| 3  | Category 3    |          |
| 4  | Subcategory 1 | 1        |
| 5  | Subcategory 2 | 2        |
| 6  | Subcategory 3 | 3        |
```

Comment: Depends on what queries you are going to run on that table. Can you please post the most relevant queries that use this table (possibly in two variants for your alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

Both seems wrong. Assuming that you have :

- 1 category can have multiple subcategories
- 1 subcategory can have one category

If so : make two tables joined by a foreign key.

In RDBMS, the 'R' means RELATIONNAL.

```
CREATE TABLE Category (id int primary key, name varchar(255));
CREATE TABLE SubCategory (id int primary key, name varchar (255), idCategory int references Category (id));
```

Imagine that one day : 
You have to add a subtype to your subcategories : you will have to add a column that will be mostly null and be carefull with a rule that no category will have a subtype (because it will have to be only a subcategory attribute). Trust in normal forms (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/normal-forms-in-dbms/)

By all means :
never forget that a numerous number of columns instead of relations between tables is a bad idea in most cases. (anti-pattern 3 : https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9860/30462074badbb819e0804a0bdba79fd6b915.pdf)

Comment: Since categories and subcategories have the same columns wouldn't it be better to put them in the same table and do a self join? Why wouldn't that be relational?

Comment: Because of normal forms  (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/normal-forms-in-dbms/).

Comment: For example: if one day you have to add a subtype to your subcategories : you will have to add a column that will be mostly null and be carefull with a rule that no category will have a subtype (because it will have to be only a subcategory attribute). Trust in normal forms.

Comment: And to be complete : never forget that a numerous number of columns instead of relations between tables is a bad idea in most cases. (anti-pattern 3 : https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9860/30462074badbb819e0804a0bdba79fd6b915.pdf)

Comment: Edited my post with those comments.